# Python numpy statsmodels OLS Regression specific value

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels

Hello Community I have this code below that implements multi-regression linear analysis and displays multiple statistical data based of the x and y values:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,4,3,4]

x = [
     [4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,4,8,9,8,8,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],      #<-x1
     [4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5],      #<-x2
     [4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,4,4]       #<-x3
     ]

x = np.array(x).T
x = sm.add_constant(x)
results = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=x).fit()
print results.summary()
```

Which Returns:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.535
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.461
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     7.281
Date:                Tue, 19 Feb 2013   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00191
Time:                        21:51:28   Log-Likelihood:                -26.025
No. Observations:                  23   AIC:                             60.05
Df Residuals:                      19   BIC:                             64.59
Df Model:                           3                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.2424      0.139      1.739      0.098        -0.049     0.534
x2             0.2360      0.149      1.587      0.129        -0.075     0.547
x3            -0.0618      0.145     -0.427      0.674        -0.365     0.241
const          1.5704      0.633      2.481      0.023         0.245     2.895

==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        6.904   Durbin-Watson:                   1.905
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.032   Jarque-Bera (JB):                4.708
Skew:                          -0.849   Prob(JB):                       0.0950
Kurtosis:                       4.426   Cond. No.                         38.6
```

How can I implement the statsmodel api just to return/print ONLY the R^2 Value(0.535) as an integer? I would like to utlize this value for multiple regression analysis and grab the highest R^2 value when the analysis is completed.
Thanks

Comment: rsquared is between 0 and 1 if you include a constant, see J Kelly's answer for how to access it. More generally, rsquared doesn't penalize including more variables and is maximized if you include every variable available. That's not a problem if you only compare models with the same number of explanatory variables, but for evaluating models with different number of variables AIC, BIC or adjusted rsquared would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print results.rsquared

What do you mean by "as an integer"?  round to 1 or 535?

Comment: I just meant to get the r squared value as I am going to use it for further calculations! Thanks for the help